# Error Single stepping in implementing a counter

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanted to create a counter that updates by one, every time it satisfied a condition in the if block of my code. To achieve this, i implemented a single tone instead of defining a global variable
In .h file………

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject {
int *counterplus;
}
@property(nonatomic) int *counterplus;
+(MONbject*) sharedinstance;
@end
```

In the .m file

```
static MON object * sharedinstance;
@implementation MONbject;
@synthesize counterplus;

+(MONbject*)sharedinstance
{
if(!sharedinstance){
sharedinstance=[[MONObject alloc]init];
}
return sharedinstance
}
-(MONObject*) int
{
self=[super init];
if(0!=self){
counterplus=0;
}
return self;
}
@end
```

I call the above as…

```
if(condition){
[MONObject sharedinstance].counterplus++;
}
```

when i try to print the value of it using `NSLog`, program stops and give this error
“single stepping until exit from function objc_msgSend, which has no line number informatiopn. warning remote failure reply: E37

I have no clue at all. I tried to used a global variable by defining it as extern and tried to
increment. But it give the same error.
Is there any way to achieve this? Can you please point me the error in it.

Comment: Could you please tell how you do your NSLog?

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas! I changed the code as you instructed but same error gets repeated! When i check the value of the counter in the debugger it seems to work well, it gets increment, I think the problem occurs when i try to print the value using NSlog . I have no idea at all. When i remove NSlog from the code, code gets executed and show the value of the counter in the debugger. But when i put NSlog in my code, it stops giving that error i have mentioned above. Any idea about it? Thanks for ur valuable time.

Comment: Again, could you tell how you NSLog it? (put the code...) I assumed that the issue was not related with the `int *counterplus` (you can have pointers to ints...) although again I don't think it's what you want...

Comment: As you said, your correct sir! The way i tried to print was wrong i guess, i used NSLog(@"counter : %@",[MONObject sharedinstance].counterplus). When i changed to NSLog(@"%d", [MONObject sharedinstance].counterplus); it works, any thought for my knowledge?

Comment: I recommend reading the following: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog. More: `int i = 12345; NSLog( @"%@", i ); // Signal 10 SIGBUS error
NSLog( @"%d", i );
i (an int) is not an object! So you can't send description to it (see above)`

Comment: Thank you sir! I m new to xcode and ios, your link helped me to learn a good lesson!

Comment: Hi guys, i need one more help from you guys, I used my counter update in the -(void) viewDidLoad function which increments the value by comparing accelerometer reading. Eg: if(accelreading(n+1)>accelreading(n) ){ counter++} ...But the problem is it updates every times the code runs through one reading loop without considering the condition in the if loop. I have no clue, seems counter result is irrespective of the if condition. please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be -

```
@property(nonatomic) int counterplus;
```

instead of -

```
@property(nonatomic) int *counterplus;
```

For Logging int values, use -

```
NSLog(@"%d", counterplus);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas! I changed the code as you instructed but same error gets repeated! When i check the value of the counter in the debugger it seems to work well, it gets increment, I think the problem occurs when i try to print the value using NSlog . I have no idea at all. When i remove NSlog from the code, code gets executed and show the value of the counter in the debugger. But when i put NSlog in my code, it stops giving that error i have mentioned above. Any idea about it? Thanks for ur valuable time

Comment: @sam - check edited post, i think you are using %@ directive to print the int value, due to which it fails.

Comment: Ohh yeah... Itz a simple mistake i have done and wasted almost a day wondering about the results. It works now! Thanks! You are the hero of the day for me! :)

Comment: @sam +1 for the link to the "tutorial". :P

Comment: Hi guys, i need one more help from you guys, I used my counter update in the -(void) viewDidLoad function which increments the value by comparing accelerometer reading. Eg: if(accelreading(n+1)>accelreading(n) ){ counter++} ...But the problem is it updates every times the code runs through one reading loop without considering the condition in the if loop. I have no clue, seems counter result is irrespective of the if condition. please help me!

Comment: have you tried debugging it whether it goes inside loop or not?

Comment: yes it runs inside the loop, seems like it goes through the if loop and agrees it conditions and increment the counter.if condition used   if(([NSNumber numberWithFloat:([[[shared sharedInstance].y objectAtIndex:0] floatvalue]>=0.00f)]))  {
[MONObject sharedinstance].counterplus++;
}
Can't figure out the bug! :)

Comment: you can check this by logging the values, that will give you clear idea why this is happening?

Comment: The way i tried to compare values was wrong! Found the bug! :)

Answer (score 0):

it shud be

```
@interface MONObject : NSObject {
int counterplus;
}
@property(nonatomic, assign) int counterplus;
+(MONbject*) sharedinstance;
@end
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your ideas! I changed the code as you instructed but same error gets repeated! When i check the value of the counter in the debugger it seems to work well, it gets increment, I think the problem occurs when i try to print the value using NSlog . I have no idea at all. When i remove NSlog from the code, code gets executed and show the value of the counter in the debugger. But when i put NSlog in my code, it stops giving that error i have mentioned above. Any idea about it? Thanks for ur valuable time